# Byte Array to font from my solution resources folder

Tags: c#, .net, fonts

I have Specific `Font` in my `resources` folder that i want to use.

```
Label label;
label.FontFamily=MyNamespace.Properties.Resources.
```

I can see my `Font` name but this return `Byte[]`.
How can i use it as `Font` ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this function

```
private System.Drawing.Font GetFontFromResource()
{
 Stream fontStream = this.GetType().Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("yourfont.ttf");

      byte[] fontdata = new byte[fontStream.Length];
      fontStream.Read(fontdata,0,(int)fontStream.Length);
      fontStream.Close();
      unsafe
      {
        fixed(byte * pFontData = fontdata)
        {
          return new  System.Drawing.Font((System.IntPtr)pFontData, 16, FontStyle.Regular);
        }
      }
}
```

How load resource from assembly:(`YourNamespace.file.ttf`):
[image]

Comment: I don't want to load the font but only from resources folder

Comment: ok, it loads font from resource folder and converts it to `Font`. then you can use it for `Label.Font`. :) is it clear?

Comment: But what should i write inside "yourfont.ttf" ? just the font name ?

Comment: @markyer, you would write `MyNamespace.Properties.Resources.yourfont.ttf` :).